# Why Apache Spark not re-submit failed tasks?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fault-tolerance

I want to simulate fault-tolerance behavior. I wrote "hard" function, that failed from time to time. for example:

```
def myMap(v: String) = {
  // print task info and return "Ok" or throw exception
  val context = TaskContext.get()
  val r = scala.util.Random
  val raise = r.nextBoolean()
  println(s"--- map $v in partition ${context.partitionId()} in stage ${context.stageId()} raise = $raise")
  if ( raise )
    throw new RuntimeException("oh ;(")
  "Ok"
}
```

Because Spark has fault-tolerance ability, I expected that failed tasks will be re-executed automatically, but it does not with the following code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext, TaskContext}

object Example {

  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.WARN)
    Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.WARN)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("shuffle example")
      .setMaster("local[*]")
      .set("spark.task.maxFailures", "4") // it is default value

    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)


    val l:RDD[String] = sc.parallelize(List( "a", "b", "c"), 3)

    def myMap(v: String) = {
      // print task info and return "Ok" or throw exception
      val context = TaskContext.get()
      val r = scala.util.Random
      val raise = r.nextBoolean()
      println(s"--- map $v in partition ${context.partitionId()} in stage ${context.stageId()} raise = $raise")
      if ( raise )
        throw new Exception("oh ;(")
      "Ok"
    }

    println (l.map(myMap).collect().mkString("\n")) // failed 

    sc.stop()
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, spark not support fault-tolerance in local mode.

In example above, if set mater to some master of standalone (or yarn) cluster, make jar-file, and run it via spark-submit, behavior will be as expected: some tasks will be failed, but re-submited. If the application has some singleton (object in Scala), it will be keep own state across failed tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The Random variable "r" would return true/false randomly without any relation with spark execution.

When you initialise :

```
val r = scala.util.Random
val raise = r.nextBoolean()
```

raise gets a random generate true or false. So you

```
 if ( raise )
        throw new Exception("oh ;(")
      "Ok"
```

is working randomly. I don't get what are you trying to achieve. 
I get the following output

```
--- map a in partition 0 in stage 0 raise = true
--- map b in partition 1 in stage 0 raise = false
```

When I re-run it I get

```
--- map a in partition 0 in stage 0 raise = false
```

raise is an randomly generated boolean value so sometime it would fail on a sometime on b.

Comment: Yes, task randomly executed or failed. I expected, that spark re-submit (re-execute) failed task.

Comment: Spark would re-submit your task because of an internal failure not because of a user thrown exception.

Comment: Ok, I tried throw SparkException and RuntimeException, but result is same. Actually I want to simulate fault-tolerance behavior. How I can do one?

Comment: The reason's because of which spark would re-submit your task could be: Executor not responding(no heartbeat signal) or data corrupted etc. which you can not replicate on a single node. What you can try to do is on a hadoop cluster you submit a job and restart one of the node which would make your executor non-responding.

Comment: Thank you for idea, but restart node is not important. Throw exception in application is enough